# Arquitectura Azure AD Resource Groups

Tags: azure

Por favor, podriais indicarme las desventajas y ventajas de usar los recursos de los entornos de Stage y Dev en un solo Resource Group? Como informacion: El acceso a estos recursos es comun y el ciclo de vida sera el un 90% el mismo. Que otros factores pueden afectar?

Muchas gracias

Comment: los grupos de recursos ayudan a la gestión de los recursos con más detalle (granuralidad) de la metada (recursos, servicios, etc.) que vas a crear en azure, por tanto, no es conveniente a nivel arquitectura combinar/mezclar dos etapas distintas del proyecto. dicho esto, me parece que a nivel de funcionalidad no habría problemas.

Comment: @lsanchezo. Gracias por la respuesta. Es lo que necesitaba saber exactamente.